# How to export high resolution ggplot graphic with unicode arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I am struggling to export the following `ggplot2` graphic (legend) with Unicode arrows.
**This is the Plot Zoom output.**

[image: Text]

The code used to create this legend is the following:

```
legend <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(
    data = bivariate_color_scale,
    mapping = aes(
      x = gini,
      y = mean,
      fill = fill)
  ) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  labs(y ="Higher bus. density →",
       x = "Higher patent growth →", 
       title = "Legend") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank() 
    ) +
  # make font small enough
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 8)) +
  # quadratic tiles
  coord_fixed()
```

I have tried to export this legend (in high resolution) with the following two codes:

```
ggsave(filename="legend.png", 
       plot = legend,
       dpi= 300,
       width = 210, 
       height = 180, 
       units = "mm")
```

and ...

```
ggsave(filename="legend.pdf",
       plot = legend, 
       dpi = 300, 
       device = cairo_pdf,
       width = 210, 
       height = 180, 
       units = "mm"
       )
```

Both codes did not properly translate/save the Unicode arrows (see the following output).

[image]

Does anybody have a suggestion on how I can export this graphic in high resolution with Unicode arrows?
thank you in advance.

---

**Data**

```
bivariate_color_scale <- data.frame(gini = rep(1:3, 3), mean = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                                    fill = c("#beafc4", "#ae667c", "#9c263c",
                                             "#778fbd", "#6d5577", "#63233b",
                                             "#3970b3", "#354374", "#301d39"))
```

Comment: It seems likely that this is a font issue. I couldn't replicate it on my machine. A couple of things to try are 1) instead of using the arrow symbol in your string use `\U2192` . 2) try a different font family - maybe try `theme(text = element_text(family = "serif"))`

Comment: Also, you're more likely to get help with a reproducible example. I've added some data at the bottom of your question that can be used with your code to recreate the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For display of Unicode characters you can use `expression()`, or (my preference) use `sprintf()`, then call the character inline with text using the preamble `\u`.  See the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  labs(
    title=paste("This Title has an up arrow!", sprintf('\u2191')),
    x=paste('The x axis goes this way:', sprintf('\u2794')),
    y=paste('The y axis is this way:',sprintf('\u2190'))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This has worked super fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that you need to use a font that actually contains the unicode symbol you want to show. You're not specifying a particular font, so the graphics device is free to choose, and both `png()` and `pdf()` choose Helvetica which doesn't have your symbol. The interactive device probably choses Arial (are you on Windows?), which does have the symbol.

```r
# code setup
library(ggplot2)

bivariate_color_scale <- data.frame(gini = rep(1:3, 3), mean = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                                    fill = c("#beafc4", "#ae667c", "#9c263c",
                                             "#778fbd", "#6d5577", "#63233b",
                                             "#3970b3", "#354374", "#301d39"))

legend <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(
    data = bivariate_color_scale,
    mapping = aes(
      x = gini,
      y = mean,
      fill = fill)
  ) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  labs(y ="Higher bus. density →",
       x = "Higher patent growth →", 
       title = "Legend") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank() 
  ) +
  # quadratic tiles
  coord_fixed()
```

```r
# with Helvetica the symbol doesn't show
legend +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Helvetica"))
```

[image]

```r
# with Arial the symbol shows
legend +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>